# Should I use the __block specifier on an object pointer even though it works without it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, variables, block

I am using a `CAAnimation` completion block (using [CAAnimationBlocks](https://github.com/xissburg/CAAnimationBlocks)) to provide processing at the end of an animation and part of that completion block modifies the animated `CALayer`.  This works even if `layer` isn't declared with the `__block` specifier, given the object pointer remains constant, however I am really treating the object as read/write.

One aspect of the [Apple Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html) that bothers me is:

> __block variables live in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or
>   created within the variable’s lexical scope.

Given the `layer` is a collection iterator, that looks to me like it will actually break if I do use the `__block` specifier.

Here is the code in question:

```
for (CALayer *layer in _myLayers)   // _myLayers is an ivar of the containing object
{
    CAAnimationGroup *group = ...;
    ...
    group.completion = ^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                         forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
        layer.position = [self _findPosition];
        [CATransaction commit];

        [layer removeAnimationForKey:@"teleportEffect"];
    };

    [layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"teleportEffect"];
}
```

My actual question is: Am I doing this right (my spider sense is tingling).

**EDIT** I should also add that my app uses MRR, however there are no issues with retain/release given the layers are *static* in nature (their lifetime is that of the containing `NSView`).  Also I appear to be doing precisely what the *Patterns to Avoid* section of the [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html) say I shouldn't do, although it's not clear (to me) why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

As to your concern with the [Anti-patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html) you mention, I think that in both anti-pattern examples, the critical point is the the variable declaration and the "block literal" assigned to it have different scope. Take the `for` case presented there:

```
void dontDoThis() {
  void (^blockArray[3])(void);  // an array of 3 block references

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    blockArray[i] = ^{ printf("hello, %d\n", i); };
    // WRONG: The block literal scope is the "for" loop
  }
}
```

1. `blockArray` is visible within the whole method body;
2. in the `for` loop, you create a block; a block is an object (some storage in memory) and has an address; the block as an object has "stack-local data structure" (from the reference above), i.e., it is allocated on the stack when you enter the method;
3. the fact that the "block literal" is treated as a variable local to the `for` loop, means that that storage can be reused at each successive iteration;
4. the block addresses are assigned to `blockArray` elements;
5. when you exit the `for` loop, `blockArray` will contain addresses of blocks that are possibly not there anymore and/or have been overwritten at each step depending on what the compiler does to stack data structure created within a `for` scope.

Your case is different, since your local variable is also within the `for` scope, and it will not be visible outside of it.

The case presented as an anti-pattern is similar to this:

```
 {
 int array[3];

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    int a = i;
    array[i] = &a;
    // WRONG: The block literal scope is the "for" loop
 }
```

Very likely, the `a` variable within the `for` scope will be allocated on stack just once and then reused at each iteration of the loop. In principle, `a` (one copy) will be still there (I am not sure, actually, the C standard should be inspected) outside of the loop, but it is pretty clear that the meaning of that code is not really sensible.

OLD ANSWER:

> __block variables live in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or created within the variable’s lexical scope.

I think this can be better understood like this: the lexical scope of the `__block` variable and all blocks (as per above definition) will share the same storage for that variable. So, if one block (or the original lexical scope) modifies the variable (I mean here the variable pointing to the object), that change will be visible to all others.

Given this, one effect of declaring a variable as `__block` is that *in the non-ARC case* the object pointed-to by it will **not** be automatically retained by each block where it is passed into (with ARC, the retain is done also for `__block` variables).

Both when using ARC and not using ARC, you need to use the `__block` specifier when you want to change the variable value and want that all blocks use the new value. Imagine that you had a block to initialize your `_myLayers` ivar: in this case, you would need to pass the `_myLayers` variable into the block as a `__block` variable, so that it (vs. a copy of it) can be modified.

In your case, if you are not using ARC, then, it all depends on whether the object pointed to by `layer` will be still there when the block is executed. Since `layer` comes from `_myLayers`, this converts into whether the object owning `_myLayers` will be still there when the block is executed. The answer to this is normally yes, since the block we are talking about is the completion block for an animation on that layer. (It would have been different, say, if it were the completion block for a network request).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So really the `__block` specifier in this case relates more to memory management rather than *mutability*?  There are no issues with memory management but I was concerned that I wasn't following the mutability aspect of the specifier.

Comment: The mutability aspect refers to the variable, not the object pointed-to by it. You might pass a variable into a block with a `nil` value; and then this might be modified later, and all blocks would then access the new object.

Comment: Looks like I'm OK then.  Can you comment on my apparent violation of the *Patterns to Avoid* at the end of my question.  Why are those patterns to be avoided?

Comment: @sergio not sure if misunderstand your answer but i`m quite sure `__block` when compiling as non-ARC specifies that the variable is mutable and that it should be treated as a pointer and not a object reference and that this has the effect that the object is not retained/released if the block is copied. If the block is not copied objects are not retained/released at all even if then are `auto` (the default) or `__block`. That is what my tests show and how I understand the [LLVM spec for blocks](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.txt)

Comment: @MattiasWadman, thank you very much for pointing that out! I modified my answer to explain correctly what happens in the non-ARC case.

Comment: Nice. But note as i said that retain of non-__block object reference variables is only done once the block is actually copied using `[block copy]` or `Block_copy`. Not really sure how this works with ARC. When i did some experiments without calling copy myself it did not trigger any retain messages.

Answer (score 4):

`__block` variables are mutable within the block (and the enclosing scope) and are preserved if any referencing block is copied to the heap.

I don't think that in your case you need a block variable because you are changing the value of the object `layer` inside the block, since it belong to the `_myLayers` array that seems to be an instance variable it is difficult that the object will be released before each block performed ... However you can add the `__block` storage type modifier to retain the object, but *if you are using **ARC**, object variables are retained and released automatically as the block is copied and later released*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; it looks to me like I might also be doing precisely what the *Patterns to avoid* section of the guide says I shouldn't do: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html

Comment: Once again, thanks for your answer, however I marked @sergio's as *the* answer as he covered other concerns I had.

Comment: if you are not using ARC, object variables are also retained and released automatically as the block is copied and later deallocated